# Left control key not working via multiple input devices

Tags: windows-10, razer-mouse, razer-keyboard, razer-synapse

This is a weird one and I have no idea how to approach it. I found another question that was similar, but the user's own solution does not seem to help me.

Recently, Windows 10 has not been registering left control key clicks. This is immensely annoying, as that is the control key I use regularly.

**I don't believe it is a hardware issue because I have registered left control to a mouse button via Razer Synapse and that doesn't work either.**

So far I have tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling the device drivers via device manager
- updating Razer Synapse
- updating windows 10

Nothing seems to work. I could really use some help on this one -- very frustrating.